# Python equivalent of array of structs from MATLAB

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, dictionary, struct

I am familiar with the struct construct from MATLAB, specifically array of structs. I am trying to do that with dictionary in Python. Say I have a initialized a dictionary:

```
samples = {"Name":"", "Group":"", "Timeseries":[],"GeneratedFeature":[]}
```

and I am provided with another dictionary called `fileList` whose keys are group names and each value is a tuples of file-paths. Each file path will generate *one* sample in `samples` by populating the `Timeseries` item. Further some processing will make `GeneratedFeature`. The name part will be determined by the filepath.

Since I don't know the contents of `fileList` a priori, **in MATLAB if** `samples` were a struct and fileList just a cell array:

```
fileList={{'Group A',{'filepath1','filepath2'}};{'Group B',{'filepath1', 'filepath2'}}}
```

I would just set a counter `k=1` and run a `for` loop (with a different index) and do something like:

```
k=1;
for i=1:numel(fileList)
    samples(k).Group=fileList{i}{1};
    for j=1:numel(fileList{i}{2})
        samples(k).Name=makeNameFrom(fileList{1}{2}{j})
        .
        .
    end
    k=k+1
end
```

But I don't know how to do this in python. I know I can keep the two for loop approach with

```
for (group, samples) in fileList:
   for sample in samples:
```

But how to tell python that samples is allowed to be an array/list? Is there a more pythonic approach than doing for loop?

Comment: OMG!! `append`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store your dictionary itself in a list and simply append new dictionaries in every iteration of the loop:

```
samplelist = []
samplelist.append(samples.copy()) % dictionary copy needed when duplicating
```

Accessing the elements in the list would then work as follows (For example the 'Name' field of the i-th sample):

```
samples_i_name = samplelist[i]["Name"]
```

A list of all names would be accessible by a simple list comprehension:

```
namelist = [samplelist[i]["Name"] for i in range(len(samplelist))]
```

Comment: Thanks...I am able to access it like you said `samplelist[i]["Name"]` but what if I wanted all names at once? Python says: 

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

when I use `[:]` notation.

Comment: Use a list comprehension (essentially a for loop in one line: `namelist = [samplelist[i]["Name"] for i in range(len(samplelist))]`